# Using Xml add Home Icon in ToolBar and resize it

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to add an icon in place of Title icon (the leftmost icon) on ToolBar  Using XML .. tried several ways (android:logo, android:icon in manifest) unfortunately no success.

Is there any way to add icon, resize the icon & add spacing between icon and title using **only xml** on ToolBar?

This is my toolbar_e.xml

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar_e.TitleText" />
```

This is in my styles.xml

```html
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar_e.TitleText"   parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>
```

This is my Manifest

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can add `view` inside `ToolBar` and
set ImageButton `android:layout_gravity` according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbarxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:paddingRight="12dp"
android:paddingEnd="12dp"
android:background="@color/black"
android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" >


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_menu" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: thanks Kishore, It helped partially but I am unable to resize the image here. I tried with { android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
  android:maxWidth="42dp"  
  android:maxHeight="42dp" }

Comment: what you want to do, can you put screenshots?

Comment: like you explained ... I was able to get an icon .. and I used gravity : left as per my requirement. but the icon is bigger than I need. So I want to resize it to make it smaller.

Comment: then set fix size like android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" or make different hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxdpi icons

Comment: Ultimately that helped .. I kept {android:layout_width=wrap_content} all the time. Its strange that  android:maxWidth didn't work, apparently it works in any activity. Thanks a ton !!